# InDesign: How to export design from CMYK to PDF in RGB?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, export

Which profile should I choose in output export options?
I need to print on office printer with clean grey colors (without CMYK tints).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting CMYK PDF to RGB](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51137/converting-cmyk-pdf-to-rgb)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewH, but there is no suggestion on type of RGB profile. Is 'sRGB IEC61966-2.1' a standard?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that, without a postscript RIP, most end-user inkjet printers *expect* to see RGB data and many have no clue what CMYK color data is. This causes the printer to convert the unknown color (CMYK) to RGB... then convert the RGB to CcMmYyK for printing. So yes, you get 2 color conversion which in some scenarios can alter colors.

To export an RGB PDF from InDesign, merely choose a job option like "High Quality Print" Then adjust the `Output` options... Color Conversion set to Convert to Destination, and then setting the Destination profile to an RGB color profile.

[image]

This will use Acrobat to convert from your CMYK InDesign file to an RGB PDF.

sRGB IEC61966-2.1 is a fairly standard RGB profile, but you may also have an RGB profile specific to your printer. If you do, use that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. Office printer are not usually set to print CMYK files. Even If they have CMYK toners or paints it will change it to RGB and then to CMYK profile of the printer.
So if you want to print grey form K it should be a setting in the printing options or printer setup.

Comment: What I've read on the internet is that they still expect RGB data to be coming at them, and that’s what should be done.
Also, that 'Appearance of black...' in InDesign should be set as 'Output all blacks accurately' instead of 'Rich Black'... is that what you mean by 'to print grey form K it should be a setting in the printing options'?

Comment: I had in mind options in the "advanced" field of "print" when you have a pdf. Some printers have an option to interpret "rich black", RGB 0,0,0, or similar as just a color to print using black toner so save ink.